# My Raspberry Pi will not complete boot error "kernel panic unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179.2)"

Tags: boot

I have just started with my Pi, so have no files to save. After being connected to the internet via Wi-Fi, I rebooted and cannot complete the boot due to being `unable to mount block`.

Any help is appreciated. I am a newcomer.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you should do when you see something like this is check the root filesystem for corruption.

To do that, you need to take the SD card out and examine it using another computer.  Ideally, that computer should be running linux.  If you don't have such a system, burn a [live CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LiveCD) -- any distro will do<sup>1</sup> -- and use that.  This may be a hassle the first time, but it will make various things easier in the future.

If you are using a live CD boot it (they are slow...), open a terminal and `su root`.   You shouldn't need a password.

Insert your SD card and determine the **device node.**  The system may automount it, in which case you'll have to `umount` it.  To be more precise, it's the 2nd (ext4) partition on the card you don't want mounted.  Then, if the device node is `/dev/sdc`

```
e2fsck /dev/sdc2
```

This should produce some output and perhaps ask you questions about repairing the filesystem.  Say yes to all of them.  You can also use the `-y` switch to `e2fsck` to automate that.

Put the card back in and try again.

> after being on internet wi fi i rebooted

If by "reboot" you mean, you pulled the plug and put it back in again, don't do that.  Use the GUI to properly shutdown or else: `shutdown -H now`, wait 15 seconds, then plug it in and out.

<sup>1</sup> I'll recommend [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/get-fedora), not because I think it is so much better than anything else, but because I can guarantee the steps here will work.  I'm *almost certain* all other live CD's are equivalent for these purposes, but I haven't tried them all.  The main issue is allowing `su root` without a password hassle.